# Android SounPool not Overlap

Tags: android, sequence, audio, soundpool

I have 3 sounds that I would like to play sequentially in Android.  I have created a SoundPool and set the "maxStreams" to "1" thinking that in the for loop the sounds would play "one at a time" not all at once.  This, unfortunately, is wrong.  How do I play the sounds sequentially and NOT all at once using soundPool.  Thanks.

Comment: @ueremy: Why are you using `SoundPool` for this instead of `MediaPlayer`? The point of `SoundPool` is to offer overlapping audio.

Comment: I thought the point of SoundPool is play small clips or sounds.  MediaPlayer is for larger files / music.  After a certain amount of MediaPlayer resources have been used / player (about 7 or so) MediaPlayer causes force-closes (even after release of resources / etc) and is very buggy imo.

Answer (score 0):

The SoundPool has no queue feature. It will just stop previous sounds when a stream is needed.

> If the maximum number of streams is exceeded, SoundPool will
>   automatically stop a previously playing stream based first on priority
>   and then by age within that priority.

[SoundPool documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool.html)